# React LocalForm does not call onUpdate

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, local

I m having a problem in React with a LocalForm:

```
           <div className="row row-content">
                <LocalForm className="col-12">
                    <Row>
                        <Label htmlFor="autocompleteCounty" md={1} className="mr-1 mt-2">Judetul</Label>
                        <Col md={2} style={{ paddingLeft: "0px" }} className="mr-4 ml-1 mt-2">

                            <LocalForm onUpdate={(values) => this.handleUpdate(values)}>
                                <County />
                            </LocalForm>


                        </Col>
```

.....

and the render function of County Component is as such:

```
 var counties =
        [{ label: "Alba", value: 0 }, { label: "Arges", value: 1 },
 return (                     <Select
                                model=".autocomplete"
                                name="autocomplete"
                                value={this.state.value}
                                onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
                                options={counties}
                                placeholder="Scoala/Liceul"
                            />);
```

Also, onChange method:

```
    onChange = (v) => {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        value: v,
    });

}
```

Now, what I m trying to achieve is to get the LocalForm which contains County Component to call its update function (handleUpdate(values)), but even though County Component calls onChange when I select a particular county, onUpdate is never called ... I am a begiiner with react, I m really confused, I would be so grateful if someone provides me with help

Comment: I haven't used LocalForm, but from the documentation, I think `Control.select` component should be used here. I think you're using the select component from `react-select` library. So `model=". autocomplete"` will not have any effect, but you can try to manually call `handleUpdate` in `onChange` of select

Comment: If you want to use this `Select` component with `LocalForm` I think you'll have look at this page in the documentation: https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/guides/custom-controls.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really tried but I can't seem to really understand that and the docs on the internet is so poor in my opinion... How exactly can i pass onChange to a component as props, I m trying and I just cant get it..